# How to visualize route layer on ArcPy Jupyter Notebook (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

I tried to visualize the route between two points using ArcPy in a Jupyter notebook. The network module is activated in my Esri account. Even though it visualizes the map I can't see the route on that as the [tutorial](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/performing-route-analyses/) shows.

Here is the code I used. I guess the problem with visualization. However I can see the following message on the console.

> [esri.views.LayerViewFactory] Failed to create view for layer 'Terrain3D, id:worldElevation' of type 'elevation'

[image]

(I tried with both Windows and Linux environments and the result is still the same )

```
from copy import deepcopy
from datetime import datetime
from IPython.display import HTML
import json
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import arcgis.network as network
import arcgis.geocoding as geocoding

user_name = 'user'
password = 'pw'
my_gis = GIS('https://www.arcgis.com', user_name, password)

route_service_url = my_gis.properties.helperServices.route.url
route_service = network.RouteLayer(route_service_url, gis=my_gis)

stops = '''-3.203062,55.906437; -3.190080,55.935570'''

route_layer = network.RouteLayer(route_service_url, gis=my_gis)
result = route_layer.solve(stops=stops, 
                       directions_language='en-US', 
return_routes=True,
                       return_stops=True, return_directions=False,
                       return_barriers=False, 
return_polygon_barriers=False,
                       return_polyline_barriers=False)

my_map = my_gis.map('Braidburn Valley', zoomlevel=13)
my_map
```

Comment: Also I tried on https://notebooks.esri.com/ environment. Still no go.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own post. Instead, [Edit] the question to contain the information.

Comment: @Vince that makes sense.

Comment: Can you export the route result as a shapefile? Use matplotlib to show coordinates on a plot. If you can convert the result to shp or geojson, then you can show it by using networkx and matplotlib. another solution is using geopandas .

Comment: You appear to be using the ArcGIS Python API rather than ArcPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to separately draw the resulted route back on the map using draw function. ArcGis changes the existing map interactively in order to show the map.

```
my_map.draw(result['routes']['features']['attributes']['geometry']
```